# Appending diferent dimention arrays

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have a simlpe question regarding column stacking that I just can't solve on my own. Here is a sample of a array called `main` and and a 1D array callend `values`.

```
print(main)

[[1.04471e+00 1.04548e+00 1.04471e+00 1.04581e+00 0.00000e+00]
[1.04439e+00 1.04624e+00 1.04308e+00 1.04493e+00 1.00000e+00]
[1.04351e+00 1.04450e+00 1.04341e+00 1.04406e+00 2.00000e+00]
...
[6.16370e-01 6.17280e-01 6.11910e-01 6.16560e-01 2.15440e+04]
[6.16280e-01 6.17650e-01 6.14450e-01 6.17780e-01 2.15450e+04]
[6.14770e-01 6.19280e-01 6.06560e-01 6.15110e-01 2.15460e+04]]

print(values)
[       nan        nan        nan ... 0.00534073 0.00416329 0.00886953]
```

All I want to do is append this 1D array at the end of my main array as a 'column', like

```
[1.04471e+00 1.04548e+00 1.04471e+00 1.04581e+00 0.00000e+00   nan]
[1.04439e+00 1.04624e+00 1.04308e+00 1.04493e+00 1.00000e+00   nan]
[1.04351e+00 1.04450e+00 1.04341e+00 1.04406e+00 2.00000e+00   nan]
...
[6.16370e-01 6.17280e-01 6.11910e-01 6.16560e-01 2.15440e+04   0.00534073]
[6.16280e-01 6.17650e-01 6.14450e-01 6.17780e-01 2.15450e+04   0.00416329]
[6.14770e-01 6.19280e-01 6.06560e-01 6.15110e-01 2.15460e+04]  0.00886953]
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it at least two ways.

1. reshape your `values` array and then append it to `main` like this:

   ```
   values = values.reshape(-1, 1)
   np.append(main, values, axis=1)
   ```

   To append to column, use `axis=1` property of `np.append`. And in order for you to be able to append columns, number of rows in `main` and `values` need to be the same, so you need to reshape `values` to have 1 column and `-1` will implicitly correct the number of rows.
2. You can use `np.column_stack` to do that without reshaping `values`:

   ```
   np.column_stack((main, values))
   ```

output:

```
[[1.04471e+00 1.04548e+00 1.04471e+00 1.04581e+00 0.00000e+00         nan]
 [1.04439e+00 1.04624e+00 1.04308e+00 1.04493e+00 1.00000e+00         nan]
 [1.04351e+00 1.04450e+00 1.04341e+00 1.04406e+00 2.00000e+00         nan]
 ...
 [6.16370e-01 6.17280e-01 6.11910e-01 6.16560e-01 2.15440e+04 5.34073e-03]
 [6.16280e-01 6.17650e-01 6.14450e-01 6.17780e-01 2.15450e+04 4.16329e-03]
 [6.14770e-01 6.19280e-01 6.06560e-01 6.15110e-01 2.15460e+04 8.86953e-03]]
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NycolasMancini You are welcome. Just added another easy way to the post too if you were interested.